# Euler angles and WignerD, a question of signs

Tags: special-functions

Express a 3D point as a linear combination of Spherical Harmonics, then rotate that point to a new position and find the new expansion in SH :

```
 n = 3; carpt1 = {0, 0, 1}; sphpt1 = 
 ToSphericalCoordinates[carpt1] /. 
  Indeterminate -> 0; {Subscript[\[Theta], 1], Subscript[\[Phi], 1]} =
  Rest[sphpt1]

    old = Total[
   Table[(-1)^mr ylm[l, -mr, Subscript[\[Theta], 1], Subscript[\[Phi],
       1]] zlm[l, mr, \[Theta], \[Phi]], {l, 0, n}, {mr, -l, l}], 2] /. 
  ylm -> SphericalHarmonicY
```

the initial point was chosen at the north pole for convenience. Since the SH carry no radial info, we can rescale the amplitude to 1 :

```
ampl = old /. {\[Theta] -> Subscript[\[Theta], 1], \[Phi] -> 
  Subscript[\[Phi], 1]} /. zlm -> SphericalHarmonicY // N
```

and plot the result:

```
    plotold = 
 Show[Graphics3D[{Green, Opacity[.7], Sphere[carpt1, .05], 
    Opacity[.5]}, Axes -> True], 
      SphericalPlot3D[
       Evaluate[old/ampl /. zlm -> SphericalHarmonicY], {\[Theta], 
        0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
       PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.2]]], 
      PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

Now rotate that point pt1 to pt2 using :

```
    {\[Alpha],\[Beta],\[Gamma]}={-60\[Degree],30\[Degree], 0\[Degree]};    
(em = EulerMatrix[{\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]}] // N) // TraditionalForm    
   
{Subscript[\[Theta], 2], Subscript[\[Phi], 2]} = Rest[ToSphericalCoordinates[em . carpt1]]
```

the expansion of pt2 in SH is then :

```
new = Total[
Table[(-1)^mr ylm[l, -mr, Subscript[\[Theta], 2], 
   Subscript[\[Phi], 2]] zlm[l, mr, \[Theta], \[Phi]], {l, 0, 
  n}, {mr, -l, l}], 2] /. ylm -> SphericalHarmonicY   // Chop
```

a second plot will serve as a sanity check :

```
    Show[plotold , 
 plotnew = 
  Graphics3D[{Blue, Opacity[.7], Sphere[em . {0, 0, 1}, .05], 
    Opacity[.5]}], 
 SphericalPlot3D[
  Evaluate[new/ampl /. zlm -> SphericalHarmonicY], {\[Theta], 
   0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.2]]], 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

So far, so good, but using a WignerD rotation seems to only work if the **negative** Euler angles are input, and I don't understand why that is :

```
    (1. old) /. 
   zlm[u_, v_, \[Theta], \[Phi]] :> 
    Sum[N[WignerD[{u, k, v}, -\[Alpha], -\[Beta], -\[Gamma]]] zlm[u, 
       k, \[Theta], \[Phi]], {k, -u, u}] // Expand // Chop
```

check:

```
  % == new
```

Equivalently, we could have used the expression for 'old' and simply written:

```
    new == Total[
   Table[N[1/
        2 Sqrt[(2 l + 1)/\[Pi]] WignerD[{l, mr, 
         0}, -\[Alpha], -\[Beta], -\[Gamma]] ] zlm[l, 
      mr, \[Theta], \[Phi]], {l, 0, n}, {mr, -l, l}], 2] // Chop
```

Checking the Mma documentation and wikipedia and some other sources didn't explain it. Can anyone help?